# Error when opening visual studio 2010 solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution file that only contains one web application project. Everytime I open that file, this message always pops up:

[image: Error Message]

Then in the output window it says:

Some of the properties associated with the solution could not be read.

And here is the solution file's text:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "Web Application", "..\Web    
Application", "{2D32A179-D771-4510-9C8B-D17D50BE3AAE}"
ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
    SccProjectName = "SAK"
    SccAuxPath = "SAK"
    SccLocalPath = "SAK"
    SccProvider = "SAK"
    TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv3.5"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/Web Application"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "D:\Projects\Web Application\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\Web Application\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/Web Application"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "D:\Projects\Web Application\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\Web Application\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
    VWDPort = "51664"
EndProjectSection
 EndProject
 Global
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 1
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = server_teamprojectcollection
    SccWebProject0 = true
    SccProjectUniqueName0 = .
    SccProjectName0 = .
    SccAuxPath0 = server_teamprojectcollection
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProvider0 = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccProjectEnlistmentChoice0 = 2
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {2D32A179-D771-4510-9C8B-D17D50BE3AAE}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {2D32A179-D771-4510-9C8B-D17D50BE3AAE}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
    HideSolutionNode = FALSE
EndGlobalSection
 EndGlobal
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio as Administrator and then try opening the project. This happens for 2 reasons.

1. You are trying to open a project that you downloaded from online and the project file is marked as that.
2. You are trying to open a project that is a web application project and the project is set to use the local IIS.

It might well be that both apply to you.

If you downloaded a .zip file from the Interwebs, then before you unzip it, go into the file's properties and Unlock it, then unarchive it. This way Windows will not mark all files it contains as unsafe.

**Update:**

After reading your question in a bit more detail, I have done some research and I think the issue lies in the TFS settings contained in your solution file. They have somehow gone awry or gotten corrupted.

Try following the procedure described [here](http://alausted.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/how-to-some-of-the-properties-associated-with-the-solution-could-not-be-read/) to solve the issue. If that still doesn't work, then create a blank solution file and add the web application to the solution using existing source. You will find this under the File menu under the New menu item.

Comment: Take care to right click on the Visual Studio icon and select "Run as Administrator", rather than trying to set up a Run As script or something like that. You are looking to run VS under elevated credentials like a lot of setup programs do.

Comment: Umar, none of these 2 reasons applied to me. This web application resided in my local hard drive and I do not use local IIS.

Comment: Have you moved the solution at all? This seems to be a website project located at `D:\Projects\Web Application`. The `.sln` file should reside in `D:\Projects\Web Application` alongside other files such as `Web.config` and the `bin` folder, etc.

Comment: yes the solution file is the same folder as the rest of the web files such as web.config file, bin folder.

Comment: Have you tried the update in answer which tries to sort out your source control properties?